# TinyMCE change textarea background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

Can I change background-color of TinyMCE's textarea from white to black? 
I've tried some old tricks, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tinyMCE loads in a stylesheet that controls the background color.  Usually the file name is content.css or content.min.css

If you can find this file in your particular configuration and set the background color of the body element to black, you should be set.

For example:  http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

The style sheet is located at:

http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/skins/lightgray/content.min.css

Comment: isn't there some way to do it programatically without needing a style sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the css file content.min.css located in your theme directory. 
Change the definition of body{background-color:#fff; ...} to **body{background-color:#000; ...}**